# Binding a ComboBox using a DataContext and LINQ to SQL

Tags: c#, winforms, linq-to-sql

I have a simple SQLite database I use to track invoices.  I recently decided to write an application for it as an excuse to learn LINQ.  I found [other questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/831345/linq-sql-data-binding-to-winforms-combobox) that address this issue, but none of the solutions worked for me.

Using the O/RM designer, I modeled my database similar to the following (simplified):

```
+------------+           +----------+
|  Invoice   |           | Customer |
+------------+           +----------+
| ID         |      +----| ID       |
| CustomerID |<-----+    | Name     |
+------------+           +----------+
```

This works great for binding the invoices table to a list and seeing a list of customers, but I'm not quite getting how to bind the table of customers to a `ComboBox` while showing the `Customer` for the invoice.

Here's the code that sets up the binding:

```
InvoiceList.DataSource = _db.Invoices;  // InvoiceList is ListBox
CustomerBox.DataSource = _db.Customers;  // CustomerBox is ComboBox
CustomerBox.DataBindings.Add("SelectedItem", InvoiceList.DataSource, "Customer");
```

In this case, `_db` is the `DataContext` generated by the O/RM.

As I select different items in the invoice list, the customer box doesn't seem to show any changes I've made.  Any pointers how to correct this?  Is there a better way to setup this binding?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you looked at using a [BindingContext](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.bindingcontext.aspx)?

And here's a slightly less opaque [description](http://en.csharp-online.net/DataViews_and_Data_Binding%E2%80%94CurrencyManager_and_BindingContext) :)

Comment: I played around with it and that seemed to help.  Somehow, I went back to my original code and it's working now.  That bugs me...  Thanks for the help.