# Binding Combobox

Tags: c#, linq, data-binding, jcombobox, ext.net

I am developing a web application with Ext.Net.

How can I bind combobox from database?

This is my query:

```
dynamic getRegions = (
    from region in db.Regions 
    orderby region.RgnName 
    select region.RgnName);
```

Comment: Possible duplication of material covered in: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1817403/binding-a-combobox-using-a-datacontext-and-linq-to-sql - this might help you.

Comment: @5arx, not quite as Ext.Net controls use the `Ext.Net.Store` as an intermediary, but the general principles of databinding apply to a small extent, though there are a fair few other ways to achieve the outcome with Ext.Net (including dynamic loading client side).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just out of interests sake, here's another quick `<ext:ComboBox>` sample which demonstrates adding data to the ComboBox without using an `<ext:Store>`. Basically the same technique as using an `<asp:DropDownList>` and adding ListItem objects.

**Example**

```
<script runat="server">
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!X.IsAjaxRequest)
        {
            // Add individual Items
            this.ComboBox1.Items.Add(new ListItem("Region1", "England"));
            this.ComboBox1.Items.Add(new ListItem("Region2", "Scotland"));
            this.ComboBox1.Items.Add(new ListItem("Region3", "Wales"));

            // AddRange alternative
            // this.ComboBox1.Items.AddRange(new ListItem[] {
            //     new ListItem("Region1", "England"),
            //     new ListItem("Region2", "Scotland"),
            //     new ListItem("Region3", "Wales")
            // });
        }
    }
</script>

<ext:ComboBox ID="ComboBox1" runat="server" />
```

Cheers!

Answer (score 2):

You have to, for an `Ext.Net.ComboBox` use an `Ext.Net.Store` as far as I'm aware. For example:

```
<!-- In SamplePage.aspx -->
<ext:ResourceManager runat="server"></ext:ResourceManager>
<ext:Store runat="server" ID="Store1">          
    <Reader>
        <ext:JsonReader IDProperty="Value">
            <Fields>
                <ext:RecordField Name="Key" />
                <ext:RecordField Name="Value" />
            </Fields>
        </ext:JsonReader>
    </Reader>
</ext:Store>

<ext:ComboBox runat="server" ID="myCombo" StoreID="Store1" 
     DisplayField="Key" ValueField="Value">
</ext:ComboBox>
```

```
// In SamplePage.aspx.cs
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var getRegions = new Dictionary<string, string>();
    getRegions.Add("Region1", "England");
    getRegions.Add("Region2", "Scotland");
    getRegions.Add("Region3", "Wales");

    Store1.DataSource = getRegions;
    Store1.DataBind();
}
```

This results in a page that contains a single Ext.Net combobox that has three values displayed. You'll almost certainly need to tweak this further to get exactly what you're after (as I'm not familiar with your database schema), but it should point you in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

http://en.csharp-online.net/DataViews_and_Data_Binding%E2%80%94Single-Value_Binding